# Calculating the bounding box of GeoJSON object using JavaScript

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, extents, django

I have Django app with Leaflet on the frontend and I need to calculate the bbox of a GeoJSON object so that I can pass the coordinates to `map.fitBounds()`

I have tried some libs as well as trying the `getBounds` methods of certain objects in Leaflet, such as `FeatureGroup`, but it complained that the bounds were not defined.

Can anyone point me to a simple solution to this?

Comment: In general, map.fitBounds(featureGroupName.getBounds()) should work, as long as the FeatureGroup contains data. Have you examined the FeatureGroup to see what it looks like at the time you are trying to get the bounds?

Answer (score 29):

If you want to calculate the bounds of a GeoJSON-Layer you can do:

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(your_data).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/qgkbrjwt/

(Map zooms to Layer extent after the Layer is completely loaded).

If you want to calculate the Bounds of each single feature you can do the following:

```
var myGeoJSON = L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // assign bounds to feature
        feature.properties.bounds_calculated = layer.getBounds();
    }
}).addTo(map);

// do whatever you want with
// feature.properties.bounds_calculated
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/fxxguv0v/

(Zoom to feature function in each popup)

Comment: Fixed the demo to remove dep on ajax request http://jsfiddle.net/fxxguv0v/22/

Answer (score 5):

Use the [geojson-bbox](https://github.com/geosquare/geojson-bbox) module to calculate the bbox of any GeoJSON.

Download this [`geojson-bbox/dist /geojson-bbox.min.js`](https://github.com/geosquare/geojson-bbox/blob/master/dist/geojson-bbox.min.js) file and save it in your project.

Usage:

`.html` file

```html
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/geojson-bbox.min.js"></script>
<body>
```

`.js` file:

```js
// reading and parsing the GeoJSON file
const geojson = JSON.parse(geojsonfile);
// getting the bbox extent as an array [left, bottom, right, top] from the GeoJSON file
var gj_extent = bbox(geojson);
```

There is npm module for [geojson-bbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-bbox)

Node.js usage:

```js
// const bbox = require('geojson-bbox'); // with CommonJS
import * as bbox from 'geojsjon-bbox';
const feature = { 
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
    type: 'LineString', 
    coordinates: [
      [10, 40], [40, 30], [20, 20], [30, 10]
    ]
  }
};
const extent = bbox(feature); 
// extent is array 
// [10, 10, 40, 40]
```

Comment: Thank you @Taras for enhancing the answer.