# React-leaflet V4: how to getBounds of a GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, react

I'm new to using React-leaflet. I want to getBounds of my GeoJSON but I don't figure out how.

I want to use it instead of `[48.832,2.623], [48.900, 2.800]` in my code.

```js
<MapContainer
          zoom={10}
          scrollWheelZoom={false}
          maxZoom={14}
          center={[48.832,2.623]}
          whenReady={e => {
            mapRef = e.target;
            e.target.flyToBounds([
                [48.832,2.623],
                [48.900, 2.800]
              ]);
          }}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {data && (
            <GeoJSON data={data} 
            style={style} 
            onEachFeature={onEachFeature} />
          )}
</MapContainer>
```

In the V2 and V3 I see on other questions that we can use  `mapRef.leafletElement.getBounds()`
But no longer in tha V4 because when I use it, have got an error of:   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBounds')`

I try with the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72036361/how-to-use-getbounds-to-get-pick-up-map-ends-with-react-leaflet), but it doesn't work either

Can someone help me do it in the new version of react-leaflet please?

Comment: Are you getting the bounding box of the geojson object and passing them to flyToBounds? - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166863/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-of-a-geojson-object-using-python-or-javascript

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do

Comment: Thanks the bbox works like a charm, have a great day @CaryH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to CaryH in the comments, I can use BBox that return an array of [left, bottom, right, top] of the box that contain the entite in the GeoJSON. The docs of  [geojson-bbox is in here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-bbox)

So the code is :

```
const bbox = require('geojson-bbox');

const extent = bbox(data); 

<MapContainer
          zoom={10}
          scrollWheelZoom={false}
          maxZoom={14}
          center={[48.832,2.623]}
          whenReady={e => {
            mapRef = e.target;
            e.target.flyToBounds([
              [extent[1],extent[0]],
              [extent[3], extent[2]]
                
              ]);
          }}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {data && (
            <GeoJSON data={data} 
            style={style} 
            onEachFeature={onEachFeature} />
          )}
        </MapContainer>
```